# Access to alias value in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I have a view with these columns:

```
id   date   Kcode   InOrder   pIn   SumIn   OutOrder   pOut   SumOut   stock  LastStock
```

This view returns `in/out` of all goods order by `kCode, date, id`. It works very well, but I need a new column that returns the Average Cost of each row with this formula:

```
 buyAvg =
    if lastStok = 0 
    then buyAvg = pIn
    else 
        if InOrder = 0 then 
          if prev record Kcode = Kcode 
           then buyAvg = Prev Record buyAvg 
          else buyAvg = 0

        if InOrder <> 0 then
        if prev record Kcode = Kcode 
           then buyAvg = ((sumIn) + (LastStok*Prev Record buyAvg)) / (inOrder+LastStock) 
          else buyAvg = pIn
    end
```

Thanks.

I need a view like in this screenshot that calculates `BuyAvg`:

[image]

Comment: buyAvg formula is not clear (it seem to be mixed with comments). could you fix this please

Answer (score 0):

Better understood once you corrected the formula.
It is not easy to get the previous value for a calculated column in this case

So we can convert the calculated column into a physical column on a temporary table and use it later.

This code works but is not a good solution i think. If the old records do not change, I suggest you open a new physical column for buyAvg and it is a good idea to calculate and write it at during insert

***UPDATED Query***

```
select *, cast(null as Decimal(18,2)) as buyavg into #temp from dbo.YourTable where 1=2
;



DECLARE @id int
DECLARE @previd int
DECLARE @prvBuyAvg decimal(18,2)
DECLARE @prvKcode int
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  

SELECT Id, LAG(Id) OVER (ORDER BY Kcode,datee,id) prevId
FROM dbo.YourTable
order by Kcode,datee,id

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @id, @previd   
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       select @prvKcode = Kcode, @prvBuyAvg = buyAvg
       from #temp where id = @previd

       insert into #temp  ([Id], [date], [Kcode] , [InOrder] , [pIn] , [SumIn] , OutOrder , pOut , SumOut , stock , LastStock , buyavg) 
       select [Id], [date], [Kcode] , [InOrder] , [pIn] , [SumIn] , OutOrder , pOut , SumOut , stock , LastStock ,

       case 
       when lastStock = 0 then 
            pIn 
       else 
            case 
            when InOrder = 0 then 
                 case 
                 when @prvKcode = Kcode then 
                      @prvBuyAvg 
                 else 
                       0 
                 end
            else 
                 case 
                 when @prvKcode = Kcode then 
                      ((sumIn) + (LastStock*@prvBuyAvg)) / (inOrder+LastStock)
                 else 
                      pIn 
                 end
            end
       end as newbuyAvg
       from dbo.YourTable  where id = @id

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @id, @previd
END   
CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
;

select * from #temp
;
```

Comment: in else Condition Return 0

Comment: because we don't have access to newBuyAvg in Prev Record

Comment: how calulate this at during insert?

Comment: and if i insert new record before my row i should to calculate all records after this

Comment: in your code, i select from a CTE. replace dbo.YourTable with my cte but i have Error