# My stored procedure is too slow

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

My stored procedure is too slow. Can I make it faster?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CalBuyAvg]
    @companyCode INT
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION CalBuyAvg

    DELETE FROM dbo.tmpCalSood 
    WHERE CompanyCode = @companyCode

    DECLARE @id INT
    DECLARE @previd INT
    DECLARE @prvBuyAvg DECIMAL(18,0)
    DECLARE @prvKcode INT

    DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
         SELECT Id, LAG(Id) OVER (ORDER BY kalaCode, Tarikh, id) prevId
         FROM dbo.CalMandeVW
         ORDER BY kalaCode, Tarikh, id

    OPEN db_cursor   

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @id, @previd   

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
    BEGIN   
        SELECT @prvKcode = KalaCode, @prvBuyAvg = buyAvg
        FROM dbo.TmpCalSood 
        WHERE id = @previd

        INSERT INTO dbo.TmpCalSood ([Id], [Tarikh], [KalaCode], [kalaType], [Varede], [fiVarede], [SumVarede], 
                                    SaleMali, AnbarCode, pType, pCode, ProjectCode, CompanyCode, 
                                    Sadere, fiSadere, SumSadere, Mandeh, LastMande , buyavg) 
            SELECT 
                [Id], [tarikh], [KalaCode], 0, [Varede], [fiVarede], [sumVarede],
                SaleMali, AnbarCode, pType, pCode, ProjectCode, CompanyCode, 
                Sadere, fiSadere, SumSadere, Mandeh, lastMande, 
                CASE 
                   WHEN lastMande = 0 
                      THEN dbo.CalMandeVW.fiVarede 
                      ELSE  
                         CASE 
                            WHEN varede = 0 
                               THEN 
                                  CASE 
                                     WHEN @prvKcode = kalaCode 
                                        THEN @prvBuyAvg 
                                        ELSE 0 
                                  END
                               ELSE 
                                  CASE 
                                     WHEN @prvKcode = kalaCode 
                                        THEN ((sumVarede) + (LastMande*@prvBuyAvg)) / (varede+lastMande)
                                        ELSE dbo.CalMandeVW.fiVarede 
                                  END
                         END
                END AS newbuyAvg
            FROM 
                dbo.CalMandeVW 
            WHERE 
                id = @id

        FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @id, @previd
    END   

    CLOSE db_cursor   
    DEALLOCATE db_cursor;

    COMMIT
    RETURN 1
END
```

Comment: Of course it could run much faster. Just rewrite it to set-based solution(without cursor).

Comment: i'm Beginner in Sql! Please Help Me

Comment: First you should prepare http://dbfiddle.uk demo with sample input and output. Then describe how this procedure should work. After that SO users could provide concise answer.

Comment: i Use 2012 Sql Server

Comment: without sample input and expected output data, and table structure, and the requirements for the procedure it's impossible to help. We don't know what the procedure is supposed to be doing. Please do as lad2025 requested.

Comment: this is my First Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47362990/access-to-alias-value-in-sql-server-2012 i Change this to a Stored Procedure. it work but is slow!

Answer (score 0):

Cursors are performance killers.
Use

```
INSERT...INTO....SELECT
```

Syntax for better performance